# Understanding True/False evaluations in the context of Python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working through the EdEx 6.00.2x course online and am struggling with one portion of my code:

```py
newResistances = copy.deepcopy(self.resistances)

for drugs in self.resistances:

    resistancePicker = random.random()
    if self.resistances[drugs] == True:
        if resistancePicker < self.mutProb:
            print self.mutProb
            newResistances[drugs] = False

    elif self.resistances[drugs] == False:
        if resistancePicker < self.mutProb:
            print self.mutProb
            newResistances[drugs] = True
    print newResistances        
    return ResistantVirus(self.maxBirthProb, self.clearProb, newResistances, self.mutProb)
```

`self.resistances` is a dictionary containing drug name keys, and `True` or `False` values `{'a':True,'b':True}`. My problem is that only the first element of the dictionary seems to be evaluated and changed in the `newResistances` dictionary. Please let me know if this question is too vague/needs more context.

Comment: As a side note, you should almost never use `== True` or `== False`. Just use `if self.resistances[drugs]:` and `elif not self.resistances[drugs]:`. (But in this case, even the latter is unnecessary; just use `else:`. If you even get to that test, you already know that `self.resistances[drugs]` is not true, so why check that it's not true?)

Comment: Debug your code must be useful next time.

Comment: The whole outer `if` and `else` can be skipped and the duplicated code between their bodies combined, as its trivially easy to negate a Boolean value with the `not` keyword: `if resistancePicker < self.mutProb: newResistances[drugs] = not newResistances[drugs]`. Also consider looping over both keys and values at the same time with `for drug, resistance in self.resistances.values():`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your `return` is the wrong location. If you move it to line up with the `for`, you will see the code iterate through all keys.

I have also updated the code to remove constructs like `if predicate==True` since you could just do `if predicate:` instead.

Here's how the code should look:

```
for drugs in self.resistances:

    resistancePicker = random.random()

    if self.resistances[drugs]:
        if resistancePicker < self.mutProb:
            print self.mutProb
            newResistances[drugs] = False

    elif not self.resistances[drugs]: # or else:
        if resistancePicker < self.mutProb:
            print self.mutProb
            newResistances[drugs] = True
    print newResistances        

return ResistantVirus(self.maxBirthProb, self.clearProb, newResistances, self.mutProb)
```